# MonoDevelop 2.4.1 not running on windows 7 ultimate unable to load glibsharpglue-2

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mono, gtk

I've been doing some searching around and I can't find any answers to my question.
I am running windows 7 Ultimate right now and have installed GTK# 2.12, then monodevelop 2.4.1. When I try and open md, the loading cursor appears then disappears, and there is no process or any trace that it opened except the log file which is this:

```
ERROR: Unexpected error while scanning file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.8.1\bin\atksharpglue-2.dll (Type 'Mono.Cecil.Binary.ImageFormatException' in Assembly 'Mono.Addins.CecilReflector, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' is not marked as serializable.)
```

I haven't been able to find any information on this error. Please help?

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work after a lot of bug fixing: Just uninstall GTK# 2.12, and do the version below : http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/gtk-sharp/gtk-sharp-2.12.9-2.win32.msi

Then monodevelop 2.4 should work fine :) Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Working for me as well. Cheers!